# Coverage of integral

Tags: integration

I have problems with solving coverage of integral
$\int_{0}^{-1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{e^x - e^{2x}}}$
.
I tried to divide function under integral by $\sqrt{\frac{1}{e^{-x}}}$
and some others but always has under $\lim_{x \to 0}{f(x)/g(x)}!=const$
I have no idea what function use to make it right. Can you give me some tips ? Thanks for all help, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Don't use the word " Coverage". "Find", "Calculate" or "What is the value " are better choices.

Comment: Sorry, I need proof that integral has limit, I thought coverage means that. Really sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{e^x-e^{2x}}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}}=\int_{1/e}^{1}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x-x^2}}=\int_{0}^{1-1/e}\frac{dx}{(1-x)^{3/2}\sqrt{x}} $$
equals $2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-1/e}}\frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$ or $2\int_{0}^{\arcsin\sqrt{1-1/e}}\frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$, or 
$$2\tan\arcsin\sqrt{1-1/e}=2\sqrt{e-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks you for help :)